# InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0] = -1 is not in [0, 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

It worked well with MLP for binary classification. In LSTM and in convolution however it gives the `InvalidArgumentError`.

I found that y needs to be reshaped and I did it.
I tried x with all positive values, and model worked well.
So what is the problem with negative values?
The data is given in the code. Any ideas?

The error is like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/src/conda3_runtime/home/envs/DSX-Python35-Spark/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1326     try:
-> 1327       return fn(*args)
   1328     except errors.OpError as e:
....
File "/usr/local/src/conda3_runtime/home/envs/DSX-Python35-Spark/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[0,0] = -1 is not in [0, 10)
     [[Node: embedding_11/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](embedding_11/embeddings/read, _arg_embedding_11_input_0_3)]]
```

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM

max_features=10
maxlen=4
embedding_size=4
lstm_output_size = 1
batch_size = 2
epochs = 2

x=([[ 0,  6,  1,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 4, -4,  3,  0],
       [-1,  9,  1, -5],
       [-2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  4,  1],
       [ 4, 10, -4, -4],
       [ 0, 10, -1, -4],
       [ 3, -2,  2,  1],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0]])

y=([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

x, y = np.array(x), np.array(y)
y = y.reshape((10, 1))

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)


print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 64, input_length = maxlen ))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation="sigmoid", return_sequences=True, recurrent_activation="hard_sigmoid"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_output_size))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print('Train...')
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size)

print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

Comment: you should give the full output of the error, i guess your y shape is [1,10] instead of [10] ?y=np.array(y).transpose()?

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to give full output, that's why I gave a small piece of data. I tried y=np.array(y).transpose(). Still gives the same error.

Comment: i meant paste the error from recent traceback sentence to the end

Comment: I tried to copy but the error is very long, causing errors in sharing. I put some piece of it both from the start and the end. However, the code is ready to run in an editor. It works just as it is.

Comment: Hey! I tried with positive values for x and it works well instead of x in the code "x = np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 4))" . Now I am searching what is wrong with the negative values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvalidArgumentError indices\[i,0\] = x is not in \[0, x) in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176051/invalidargumenterror-indicesi-0-x-is-not-in-0-x-in-keras)