# Keras LSTM is not getting added

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Here is the model that I am trying to create:

```
def build_model(inputs_size):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(100,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=inputs_size, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=inputs_size, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=inputs_size, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_logarithmic_error, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

def save_model(model):
    # saving model
    json_model = model.to_json()
    open('model_architecture.json', 'w').write(json_model)
    # saving weights
    model.save_weights('model_weights.h5', overwrite=True)

def load_model():
    # loading model
    model = model_from_json(open('model_architecture.json').read())
    model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')
    model.compile(loss=losses.mean_squared_logarithmic_error, optimizer='adam',metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("training.csv", header=0,index_col=0)
print(dataframe.columns)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,:-1].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,-1]
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
model = build_model(X.shape[1])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=True)
save_model(model)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Let me know what I am missing. I guess the issue with the shape of the input but don't know what exactly to do with it.

**EDITED:** Sample dataset: [training.csv](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/3ab8ee88f3fc32e78579a1054aac757d)

Comment: Show us a sample from X_train

Comment: Sure... I will add the sample dataset with the question which I forgot.

Comment: Your first layer in the `Sequential` model is a `LSTM`. In keras, the first layer should contain the shape the of input, which is not present in your code

Comment: @SreeramTP I tried using th input_dim with the LSTM, I got this error: `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_2_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1799, 6)
`

Comment: You feed sequences of 2 dimension to the network while LSTM needs a 3D sequences. Change your input to one_hot encoding and then pass it to the LSTM or use embedding layer.

Comment: @Amir Can you please help me make it in the code?

Comment: I don't understand everything is given and I am specific on what I want. Still why a downvote? That too without any reason specified.

Comment: I tried to convert to one_hot encoding: `X = tf.one_hot(X,depth=1)`, I got the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you feed sequences of 2 dimension to the network while LSTM needs 3-dimensional sequences. Change your input to one_hot encoding and then pass it to the LSTM or use the embedding layer. Here is how your Netowrk should be:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

x = np.zeros(shape=(10000, 32, 50))
y = np.zeros(shape=(10000, 3))

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=128)
```

Pay attention to size of `x` and `y`.

**Alternative** approach:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(10000, 50))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

x = np.zeros(shape=(10000, 32))
y = np.zeros(shape=(10000, 3))

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: I tried your codes second part with Embedding, I got the error: `InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0] = -1 is not in [0, 6)
  [[{{node embedding_2/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_3/Adam/Assign_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_2/embeddings/read, embedding_2/Cast, training_3/Adam/gradients/embedding_2/embedding_lookup_grad/concat/axis)]]
`

Comment: @JafferWilson one of the entries in your input data is -1 which is not acceptable for Embedding layer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176051/invalidargumenterror-indicesi-0-x-is-not-in-0-x-in-keras/54177129#54177129

Comment: But there can be negative values in the dataset that is a part of my detection. So is there nothing can be done?

Comment: Change the indexes to start from zero or normalize your data. It depends on the problem.

Comment: I have already normalized the dataset with the `scale` function of the `sklearn.preprocessing`.

Comment: Use the first approach. Here is a complete guide on how to use LSTM on timeseries: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-network-python/

Comment: Yes it worked. I have used `MinMaxScaler. and it worked . Thank you for your advice sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in the shape : (1779, 6)

Assuming it is numeric data as I am not able to take a look at training.csv provided in the question.

If you want to pass it to a LSTM the data must be 3D. So you have to reshape the data as needed.

As a toy example consider the random data as given below.

```
X = np.random.rand(1779, 6) # some random data
X = X.reshape((1779, 6, 1)) # reshaping the data to 3D
y = np.random.rand(1779, 3) # random target feature
```

Now, in Keras Sequential model the first layer should mention the shape of the data it is expecting. So you have to set the `input_shape` parameter in `LSTM`. It can be done like this

```
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(6, 1)))
```

There is no need to provide shape parameter in any other layers of the model as Keras will handle that automatically. So the following `Dense` can be like this

```
model.add(Dense(1))
```

You are also using `init` but it now deprecated in favour of `kernel_initializer`.

Putting all together, your `build_model` function can be re written like this.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

def build_model(inputs_size):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(100,activation="relu", input_shape=inputs_size))
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(200, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

I have changed to loss function, but you can use whatever loss you need for your application.

The function can be used like this.

```
model = build_model((X.shape[1], 1))
model.fit(X, y)
```

Complete code for a toy example

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(1779, 6)
y = np.random.rand(1779, 3)

X = X.reshape((X.shape[0],X.shape[1], 1))

def build_model(inputs_size):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(100,activation="relu", input_shape=inputs_size))
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(200, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = build_model((X.shape[1], 1))

model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me but your answer is good.. May help others.

Comment: What was the problem you encountered.?

Comment: I tried reshaping as you said: `X = X.reshape((1779, 6, 1)) ` I made is something like this as I know my data shape is 2D so `X = X.reshape((X.shape[0],X.shape[1], 1))`, It didn't worked. The embedding Idea I guess worked for me. The reshaping gave me error. Had you tried it?

Comment: Yes. I have done it and I haven't encountered any error

Comment: May be I guess I need to check it once again. I will let you know the error. just give me few moment.

Comment: This is the error: `ValueError: No variables to save`, while I am trying to run the model.fit as`model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=500, verbose=True,callbacks=[tensorboard],validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
`. I hope you got the error.

Comment: What is your Keras and Tensorflow versions.?

Comment: Tensorflow '1.12.0' and Keras '2.2.4'

Comment: My tf is latest one. 1.12.0 is the latest version amigo. I think you are the one to check the tf version. What version you are using please tell me.

Comment: Oh sorry. my mistake. But the code runs fine after updating my libraries

Comment: May be not the fault of versions but the coding.. need to check.

Comment: I have updated the answer with complete code that is working fine in my machine.

Comment: I will try it once again with my data not with toy as that is the aim,right?

Comment: Had you tried the scaling or normalization over it? It may give error.

Comment: Scaling or Normalization won't give any error because it dont have anything to do with shape of the data